# Z-index absolute positioning confusion

Tags: html, css, z-index, css-animations

In the following example I am trying to get the pop out "tickets" to show in front of the other doors:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVMXVz

I have attempted to apply a higher z-index on the div.appeal-details when the article is hovered over - I'm unsure why this isn't working:

```
article:hover .record .jukebox-ticket {
  animation: growTicket 0.4s ease-in-out;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  z-index: 20;
}
```

My understanding is that the higher z-index combined with absolutely positioning should work - but clearly not.

Keen to avoid JS, but will do if needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add

`position:relative; z-index:1;`

to your `article` and for `article:hover` higher

`z-index:2;`

or 10;

Check example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvbdrB

P.S. And than there is no need in javascript part as i can understand.